# What are the plots I can do in order to select predictors?

Tags: feature-selection

First thing I do with the data is to check the relation of the variable to be predicted with other variables. To do this I produce simple plots using plot function or qplot function. I do matrix plot and box plot as well. Are there any other types of plots that I can use in order to check choose variables?

Comment: To choose variables for what?  Be clear about what it is you are trying to do.  If you are asking about variables to include in regression models, variable selection should be based on theory or previous empirical findings.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be in the stage that is usually termed *exploratory data analysis* -- any kind of visualization is potentially useful. My favourite `R` tools are:

- **Direct pairwise comparisons** with `pairs()` from `graphics` and also `corrplot()` from `corrplot` package (visualization of correlation matrices).
- There are huge possibilities for visualization complex data with **"facetted" or "trellis" plots** in `lattice` and `ggplot2` packages. Extremely effective once you get the idea how these plots work.
- **Ordination plots** from PCA, RDA, CCA, CA, multidimensional scaling, etc. All of these seek to reduce the dimensionality of your data by seeking the main axes of variation. They have two advantages: (1) They show you the co-variation in a visually cleaner way than pairplots, and (2) the extracted axes can themselves be used as predictors, which may come handy if you have a lot of correlated variables and you are unsure which one should you use.
- 3D scatterplots, contourplots, hexbin plots for data with extremely large N (`hexbin` package), ... there are probably heaps of other kinds of plots.

Comment: Is it possible to tell from pairs and plot function whether the relation is linear or not?